# Using phalcon's annotations to define multiple routes to the one controller

Tags: routes, phalcon

I am trying to use Phalcon's annotations to define my routes.

I currently have 2 different routes pointed to the same controller so that I can reuse the login:

```
$router->add("/delivery-methods/:action/:int", array(
  "controller" => "code",           
  "action" => 1,
  "id" => 2,
  "code_type" => "delivery-method"
));

//manage quarantines
$router->add("/quarantines/:action/:int", array(
  "controller" => "code",           
  "action" => 1,
  "id" => 2,
  "code_type" => "quarantine"
));
```

How can I convert this into annotations on my `Code` controller?
I tried something like:

```
/**                                
 * @RoutePrefix("/delivery-methods")  
 * @RoutePrefix("/quarantines")     
 */
```

However the second line doesn't work. I also need a way to statically say that "when the route is delivery-method, set the code_type to delivery-method" etc.

Any ideas? Or can this simply not be done through annotations?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem related with annotations ?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use 'namespace' in route parametrs like this

```
$router->add('/admin',array(
      'namespace'  => "Multiple\Admin\Controllers\\",
      'module'     => "admin",
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action'     => "index",
))->setName('adminArea');
```